# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'

Tags: python, caffe

I'm a java dev...trying to run some code in Python 3.6.8 in windows 10
for a demo. When i execute the below code i was getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe' error

so installed

```
pip install caffe-ssd-x86
```

after that i'm getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\clean_water_ai-master\mycode\code.py", line 10, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "C:\Users\Ela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "C:\Users\Ela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'
```

code as follows, share your inputs on addressing the issue

This code is part of clean water ai code application from https://www.hackster.io/clean-water-ai/clean-water-ai-e40806#toc-step-4--collecting-data-for-ai-6

```
import os
import glob
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2

import caffe
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
import lmdb
#Size of images
IMAGE_WIDTH = 227
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 227
def transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT):
   #Histogram Equalization
   img[:, :, 0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img[:, :, 0])
   img[:, :, 1] = cv2.equalizeHist(img[:, :, 1])
   img[:, :, 2] = cv2.equalizeHist(img[:, :, 2])
   #Image Resizing
   img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
   return img
def make_datum(img, label):
   #image is numpy.ndarray format. BGR instead of RGB
   return caffe_pb2.Datum(
       channels=3,
       width=IMAGE_WIDTH,
       height=IMAGE_HEIGHT,
       label=label,
       data=np.rollaxis(img, 2).tostring())
train_lmdb = 'C:/clean_water_ai-master/mycode/face_training/input/train_lmdb'
validation_lmdb = 'C:/clean_water_ai-master/mycode/face_training/input/validation_lmdb'
os.system('rm -rf  ' + train_lmdb)
os.system('rm -rf  ' + validation_lmdb)
train_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/train/*jpg")]
test_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/test1/*jpg")]
#Shuffle train_data
random.shuffle(train_data)
print ('Creating train_lmdb')
in_db = lmdb.open(train_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
   for in_idx, img_path in enumerate(train_data):
       if in_idx %  6 == 0:
           continue
       img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
       img = transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT)
       if 'yeast' in img_path:
           label = 0
       else:
           label = 1
       datum = make_datum(img, label)
       in_txn.put('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx), datum.SerializeToString())
       print ('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx) + ':' + img_path)
in_db.close()
print ('\nCreating validation_lmdb')
in_db = lmdb.open(validation_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
   for in_idx, img_path in enumerate(train_data):
       if in_idx % 6 != 0:
           continue
       img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
       img = transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT)
       if 'yeast' in img_path:
           label = 0
       else:
           label = 1
       datum = make_datum(img, label)
       in_txn.put('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx), datum.SerializeToString())
       print ('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx) + ':' + img_path)
in_db.close()
print ('\nFinished processing all images')
```

Comment: did you install `caffe`?

Comment: i've installed pip install caffe-ssd-x86 after that i'm getting following error 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'